# Bootstrap sticky nav unable to overflow outside of container when sticky?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a sticky navbar in Bootstrap to display correctly. When 'un-stuck' it all fits inside the container. When 'stuck' the logo gets inserted, this is causing it to wrap because the container is to small for all the elements.

I'm trying to insert the logo li element just to the left of the navbar container to fix the wrapping issue but having no success.

URL: https://lasereyestage.wpengine.com/

Relevant Code (Inside a container div):

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar3" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav locked" id="navbar">
        <li class="home-link">
            <a href="https://lasereyestage.wpengine.com/">
                    <img src="/wp-content/themes/lasereyeinstitute/images/logo_small.png" alt="Laser Eye Institute" id="lei" class="logo-hide" style="display: inline;">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-137" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-137"><a href="https://lasereyestage.wpengine.com/our-story/">Our Story</a></li>
       [...]
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS to position the li>home-link outside of the container (Works when stuck, but offsets and breaks the nav when un-stuck

```
.home-link{margin-left:-100px;}
```

- Should i just conditionally apply the negative margin only if stuck?
- Is there a better way of doing this without a negative margin?
- Should i not do this at all and find a way to fit it all in the container instead of trying to break out of the container?

Comment: looks good for me? Could you further explain what you mean by wrapping issue?

Comment: @johnSmith Change the width of your browser window, and you'll understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to put a 2 meter stick into a 1 meter box. It's not gonna fit.
The browser helped you by cutting up the stick into 2 sticks of 1 meter, now it fits but you ended up with 2 sticks.

If you don't want to cut up the stick you have 2 options:

- Get a bigger box
- Get a smaller stick

## Bigger Box

You can get a bigger box by moving the `.navbar` outside of the `.container`
You'll probably want to add some padding/margin for when it's un-sticky. And remove that once it gets stickied. Extra points for making it transition smoothly.
[image]

### Or get a smaller stick;

Rearrange your menu items into sub-menus, bootstrap supports [dropdowns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#nav) in navbars.
You can hide the sub-menus when the bar is un-sticky and show them when it gets sticky.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the Font size when it goes to stick. Same for margins and paddings.

No need to give explicit heights and widths since you using bootstrap. It should be automatic.

Why not use the full width sticky

> Should i just conditionally apply the negative margin only if stuck?

No. You should no apply explicit margin. It might work good in your screen but in different sizes screens it might not.

> Is there a better way of doing this without a negative margin?

Use Full Screen width.

> Should i not do this at all and find a way to fit it all in the
>   container instead of trying to break out of the container?

Apply the font size fix and your good to go. But my suggestion is to make two different navbar menus, one for mobile and one for desktop. So they wont clutter with each other.